# SIGABRT error after adding SKProduct to NSMutableArray in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, in-app-purchase, sigabrt

I am adding the purchased items to an array so I can retrieve data and display them in a tableview easily.. However I am getting sigabrt error.. What is my problem with the code below?

tableView

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Default Gun";
            break;

        case 1:

            cell.textLabel.text = [[[[GameData sharedData] gunsArray] objectAtIndex:0] localizedTitle];
            break;


        default:
            break;

    }


    - (NSMutableArray *) gunsArray {

        SKProduct *product1 = [[InAppStore sharedStore] getGun1];
        SKProduct *product2 = [[InAppStore sharedStore] getGun2];
        SKProduct *product3 = [[InAppStore sharedStore] getGun3];
        SKProduct *product4 = [[IInAppStore sharedStore] getGun4];

        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isGun1Purchased"] == YES && ![arr containsObject:product1]) {
            [arr addObject:product1];  // error occurs here

        }
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isGun2Purchased"] == YES && ![arr containsObject:product2]) {
            [arr addObject:product2];  

        }
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isGun3Purchased"] == YES && ![arr containsObject:product3]) {
            [arr addObject:product3];

        }

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isGun4Purchased"] == YES && ![arr containsObject:product4]) {
            [arr addObject:product4];

        }

        return [arr autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?  (try `bt` in the debugger console).

Comment: ... but the code you have provided is not legal (you have a method declaration in the middle of another method)!

Answer (score 1):

You probably try to insert `nil` into the array (this would result in an exception and finally into a SIGABRT). So check if one of the `product` variables is `nil`.

Oh, and you should switch to ARC (though that's unrelated to your issue).

Comment: yes u are right.. but that's very weird.. I can access to product details like `[[[InAppStore sharedStore] getGun1]localizedTitle]` but `SKProduct *product1 = [[InAppStore sharedStore] getGun1];`returns nil.. any reason??